# Grub disappear on Lenovo E531

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lenovo

Hi and Happy New Year.

I have the following problem. My Lenovo E531 have dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. The problem is, that grub just disappear. I install Ubuntu normally and use it normally. I don't install nothing yet. Today I turn on the Laptop and appears a screen that show "Grub rescue>". So I turned it off and boot from "Boot-Repair-Disk" tool.

This tool didn't offer the repair option, only the Create a Bootinfo summary option.

Here is the summary -> http://paste.ubuntu.com/14398335/

How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your disk is badly damaged. Your partition table appears to be intact and is sensible, but Boot Info Script says the partitions all contain unknown filesystems. This suggests that either the partition table information is wrong or the filesystems have all been damaged by something -- improper use of low-level commands like `dd`, a malicious virus, a failing disk, etc.

Recovery might be possible, but will require considerable expertise. If the partition table is damaged, [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) might be able to recover the partitions, but I don't think that's the problem. If I'm right in this, your best bet is likely to be to wipe everything and recover it all from a backup. You *do* have a backup, right? If not, you might be able to pull your important files off the disk with [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) or something similar, but you'll need a clean disk for recovery. The last I checked, PhotoRec did a poor job of recovering filenames, so you might end up spending a lot of time reviewing and renaming files. Some Windows-specific tools supposedly do a better job recovering filenames, but I have no specific pointers.

In case your disk is failing, you might want to [run a SMART examination](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04) of the disk before you restore data to it. If the disk is physically failing, there's no point in trying to re-install to it, since you'll just hit problems right away.

Answer (score -1):

click this link:

https://arisantos.wordpress.com/2015/05/11/troubleshooting-kendala-booting-di-ubuntu-14-04-dan-muncul-grub-rescue/

may be your solution :)

Comment: It's much better to provide the required steps in your answer. If the link breaks, then the entire answer would become useless.

Comment: @Minos It doesn't help that the article isn't in English.